# MAC M1 STM32Cube IDE StLnik Debugging not working

Tags: macos, stm32, libusb

I am not able to resolve this problem. I hav mac M1 Macbook and i install Stm32 Cube IDe 1.13 version. I tried a simple hello world project the project is building.

But the problem comes when i try to debug it. The error it shows is **libusb: info [darwin_claim_interface] no interface found; setting configuration: 1
libusb: error [darwin_claim_interface] could not set configuration**

The output is below -

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 7.4.0
Copyright (c) 2023, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled

libusb: info [darwin_claim_interface] no interface found; setting configuration: 1
libusb: error [darwin_claim_interface] could not set configuration
Device connect error

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: Failed to connect to device. Please check power and cabling to target.
```

I need help to make it work. My Mac Os is 13.5 Ventura.

If u r wondering about my debug setting than those are
[image]

Comment: Did you installed the [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html#overview), if you did, does it work when you run the STM32CubeProgrammer alone?

Comment: The STM32CubeIDE = compiler + debugger + STM32CubeProgrammer. Problem is with debugger. STM32CubeProgrammer and compiler are ok they are working.